# How to extract an array of binary values from a CGImage in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, pixel

I am using a getPixelColor function (printed below) to extract all the pixel data from a CGImage:

```
extension CGImage{
    func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint) -> UIColor {

        let pixelData = self.dataProvider!.data
        let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

        let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4

        let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }
}
```

I am then averaging the R,G,B pixel values to calculate the intensity.
I am placing each intensity value into a 2-D array with dimensions imageWidth x imageHeight. These intensity values are then checked against a certain threshold, and accordingly assigned either a zero or one.

```
extension UIColor {
    var coreImageColor: CIColor {
        return CIColor(color: self)
    }
    var components: (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        let color = coreImageColor
        return (color.red, color.green, color.blue, color.alpha)
    }
}

var intensityArray: [[Float]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: width), count: height)
//fill intensity array with a nested for loop

for index1 in 0...height-1{  //make sure height-1 is here always

    for index2 in 0...width-1{  //(width-1) has to goes here because the last place in the array is the size-1
        let cgPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(index2), y: CGFloat(index1))  //get an "index out of range error at 250 times
        let color = cgImage?.getPixelColor(pos: cgPoint)
        let CIcolor = color?.coreImageColor
        let greencomponent = Float((color?.components.green)!)
        let redcomponent = Float((color?.components.red)!)
        let bluecomponent = Float((color?.components.blue)!)
        let alphacomponent = Float((color?.components.alpha)!)
        var intensity = (greencomponent+redcomponent+bluecomponent)/3
        if intensity > 0.9 {
            intensity = 1
        } else {
            intensity = 0
        }
        intensityArray[index1][index2] = intensity 
    }
}
```

With images larger than 100x100, this process takes very long so I was wondering if there was a simpler way to get the image pixel data in binary.

Answer (score -1):

Looked a little deeper, and my guess wasn't the major problem. The major problem was all the extra objects you're creating (you're doing way too much work here). You don't need to make a UIColor and a CIColor for every pixel just to extract back the information you already had.

Here's a sketch, lightly tested (might be a bug in the computation; you'll have to unit test it)

```
var intensityArray: [[Double]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: width), count: height)
//fill intensity array with a nested for loop

for index1 in 0...height-1{  //make sure height-1 is here always

    for index2 in 0...width-1{  //(width-1) has to goes here because the last place in the array is the size-1
        let colorIndex = (index1 * width + index2) * 4
        let red = Double(data[colorIndex]) / 255
        let green = Double(data[colorIndex + 1]) / 255
        let blue = Double(data[colorIndex + 2]) / 255

        var intensity = (red+green+blue)/3
        if intensity > 0.9 {
            intensity = 1
        } else {
            intensity = 0
        }
        intensityArray[index1][index2] = intensity
    }
}
```

This is still a long way from the fastest approach, but it's much faster than you're doing this. If you need this to be really fast, you'll want to look at `CIImage` and `CIFilter`, which has these kinds of tools built-in (though I haven't looked up how to do this specific operation; depends on what you're planning on doing with the intensities).

---

*OLD ANSWER; useful, but may or may not be the major cause on this one.*

I'm going to go out on a limb here (too lazy to actually throw it in the profiler) and blind-guess that it's this line that takes almost all your time:

```
    intensityArray[index1][index2] = intensity
```

This is not "a 2-D array." There is no such thing in Swift. This is an Array of Arrays, which is a different thing (each row could be a different length). That is very likely causing tons of copy-on-writes that duplicate the entire array.

I'd simplify it to `[Float]` and just write to `intensityArray[index1 + index2*width]`. That should be very fast (in fact, you could just use `.append` rather than subscripting at all). When you're done, you can pack it some other way if you like.

But the lesson here is that you should always start by profiling with Instruments. Don't guess where the problem is (yeah, I guessed, but I've seen this problem many times), test.

Also, double check whether this runs dramatically faster in Release mode. Sometimes these kinds of things are really slow in Debug, but fine once you optimize.

Comment: How do you suggest I declare my array? I do not completely understand how: intensityArray[index1 + index2*width] accounts for the 2-dimentionality of the image.

Comment: Create the array as size height*width. This is how 2D arrays are actually implemented in C (and most languages). a[x][y] is just syntactic sugar for a[x+width*y]. A true 2D array (where all rows have the same width) is the same as a 1D array of the product.

Comment: As it is now, is colorIndex allowing us to scan through the image left to right, going from top to bottom? Eliminating the extra objects significantly reduced the run time, thank you.

Comment: Yes; this data is laid out left to right, top to bottom.